# Similarity between bordermode and zero padding in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

In Keras, the `border_mode = 'valid'` doesn't zero pad the input. Thus, we subsequently get an output feature map that is not the same size as the input. Likewise, setting `border_mode = 'same'` gives output feature maps as the input. My question is if we set `border_mode = 'same'`, should we also perform zero padding using the `zero_padding` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer to this here https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1984. If the stride is 1, border_mode = 'same' does the job of padding to ensure that the output feature maps are the same size as the input.